# Get unique Attributes from XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, dictionary

I have the below XML. I need to get unique attributes & Tags from the XML. Could someone guide me in fetching only the unique attributes from XML.Thanks in advance!

```
<Elements>
<Details>
    <Name>ABCD</Name>
    <Address>1D23ABC</Address>
</Details>  
<Dept num = "12S3" >
    <Deptname>ITS</Deptname>
    <ID>A12S3</ID>
    <ID1>A12W3</ID1>
</Dept> 
    <Dept num = "123" >
    <Deptname>IT1</Deptname>
    <ID>A1231</ID>
    <ID1>A1213</ID1>
</Dept>
```

My output should be as below

```
Elements
Details    Name
           Address

Dept       Num
           Deptname
           ID
           ID1
```

Below is the VBA code I am using:

```vb
Set mainnode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//Elements")

 For Each node In mainnode
  Dim child As Object
    i = 0
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value = child.BaseName
            Dim kiddo As Object
                For Each kiddo In child.ChildNodes
                Debug.Print kiddo.BaseName
             Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i + 1).Value =                                                     
                kiddo.BaseName
                i = i + 1
                Next kiddo
            Next child
            Next node
```

Current Output:

```
Elements
Details    Name
           Address

Dept       Num
           Deptname
           ID
           ID1
Dept       Num
           Deptname
           ID
           ID1
```

Comment: The only actual "attribute" in that XML sample is "num" - all others you list are *elements* ("tags")

Comment: @TimWilliams - my apologies. I wanted all unique tags and attributes from the above XML.

Comment: @QHarr -  I only need the unique <tag> names irrespective of the value. I am not concerned what the value is in those tags.

Comment: You should look to get that via XSLT which would be quicker and much more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VERSION 1 regex:

With a regex (***not***  generally recommended for working with XML/HTML)

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Dim arr()  As String, dict As Object, key As Variant, i As Long
    arr = Split(GetTags(xmlDoc.XML), "##"): Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(Replace(Replace(arr(i), Chr$(60), vbNullString), Chr$(62), vbNullString)) = 1
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
End Sub

Public Function GetTags(ByVal xmlString As String) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, i As Long, matches As Object, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<([^\/].*?)>"

        If .test(xmlString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(xmlString)

            ReDim arr(0 To matches.Count - 1)
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                arr(i) = matches(i)
            Next i
        Else
            arr(i) = xmlString
        End If
        GetTags = Join(arr, "##")
    End With
End Function
```

---

Regex

[image: regex]

*[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/U8GzhV/1)*

---

**Output:**

You can remove/ignore the initial tag covering the doc type.

[image: output]

---

**References:**

Tools > References > Microsoft XML (your version e.g. 6.0)

---

### VERSION 2 Traversing tree structure:

More robust solution adapting your existing code to use a dictionary of dictionaries so tree structure can be easily written out.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, mainNode As Object, Node As Object, dict As Object, r As Long
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Set mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Elements"): Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    [B1] = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.nodeName

    For Each Node In mainNode
        Dim child As Object
        For Each child In Node.ChildNodes
            If Not dict.exists(child.BaseName) Then
                dict.Add child.BaseName, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            End If
            Dim kiddo As Object
            For Each kiddo In child.ChildNodes
                If Not dict(child.BaseName).exists(kiddo.BaseName) Then
                    dict(child.BaseName).Add kiddo.BaseName, 1
                End If
            Next kiddo
        Next child
    Next Node
    r = 0
    Dim key1 As Variant, key2 As Variant
    For Each key1 In dict.keys
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & r + 1) = key1
        For Each key2 In dict(key1).keys
             Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & r + 1).Value = key2
             r = r + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What tool is the regex screenshot from? Thanks

Comment: `Dept num = "1253"` is not part of expected output per OP, it should just be "Dept" and "num", delimited. Also doesn't output in the "tree"-view per OP. Also it's worth noting that while this might kinda work for this particular case, using RegEx to parse XML/HTML/etc is generally not considered a best practice :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Agreed in the best practice bit. It is a very bad and unreliable practice in general! Regarding whether it selects the right bits: I thought the OP's question/comments were a little confused.  "I only need the unique <tag> names irrespective of the value". I went with the latest comment. They may have disappeared now forever anyway :-(

Comment: @QHarr  -Thanks for the code. It works for the given sampel xml, however I am getting 'type mismatch' when I run the code for similar other XML's. Is there a reason to figure out the mismatch on which field. ?

Comment: I was looking for a tree structure to identify the parent and child nodes and get the unique values among them.. If there is a way to identify unique values without impacting the tree structure, kindly let me know. Thank you :)

Comment: One moment. The issue is that you are after the tags themselves rather than what is associated with them. In that case I am thinking of perhaps looping all the nodes and adding to a dict.

Comment: Updated version added.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get a tree structure with base node and child nodes seperated to identify what node falls under which parent. ? 

Also what is the use of 

Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)

Comment: Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys) writes the dictionary keys out to the range. The dict keys are the unique tag names.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I am trying to get a tree structure with the parent and child in  seperate columns. let me try. Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Just a question.

Why do you use dict(key1) instead of dict(keys) for the Key2 value

For Each key2 In dict(key1).keys

Comment: It is a dictionary of dictionaries so  dict(key1) is a dictionary, as is dict.

Comment: so when I have further child nodes, Can I increment by having
 `For Each key3 In dict(key2).Keys  Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & r + 1).Value = key3`

Comment: You may need further nested dictionaries. Traditionally you would navigate using the DOM. As you want distinct tags that is why I introduced dictionaries. One dictionary for every level with the children of that tag as keys. I recommend reading up on dictionary of dictionaries or creating your own custom classes.

Comment: Each loop in your original dom navigation equated to a level. You could concantenate variables to track levels/relationships and later split. Just a little tricker to write out nicely to the page, unlike with dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will try to look for nested dictionaries. Since as of now, when I add more keys, I am getting ALL the results in a single column

Comment: Study what is happening at each stage by stepping through code with F8, watch what is happening to variables in the locals window and use the immediate window to print values (partic if you can't inspect them directly in the locals window)

Comment: I was looking over the code with F8 and realized that the value of key1 and key2 are updated constantly. I was expecting Key1 to hold only the Parent node and Key2 to hold the immediate child node.

whereas when I complete one parent and move to another, they values in Key2 are updated as Key1 for the other parent node. , thereby causing mismatch

Comment: in your code with a different xml doc? In my code the root node is never added to the dictionary. It could but as I know it to be singular and left most I simply write it out. For the others, there is no overwrite as the only thing we care about are keys and I use a test of .Exists to determine if I add.

Comment: yes. I am getting the child nodes "details" & "dept" in Key1. Along with that, I also get their corresponding child nodes "Name" , "address" in Key1, which is causing errors.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers provided. I have decided to remove the tree structure as it takes a longer time and it creates empty cells for large xml's. Now having all the unique tags in a single column one after the other and assigning it all to a Dict Key.